# Pegar valor hidden .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Bom dia tenho esse hidden que recebe o valor corretamente:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idHorario"/>
```

Porém preciso pegar o hidden no código, como posso proceder?

```
 HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
                 .Include(a => a.Horarios)
                 .Where(a => a.HorarioId == ["hidden aqui"] )
                 .ToListAsync();
```

Não estou conseguindo passar o valor do hidden para a condição.

Edit:
Possuo esta função onde manda o HorarioId para salvar na pagina HorarioItem/Create

```js
function ListarItens(idHorario) {

    var url = "/HorarioItem/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: idHorario }
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            console.log(idHorario);
            var divItens = $("#divItens");
            divItens.empty();
            divItens.show();
            divItens.html(data);
            $("#idItem").val("0");
            $("#idHorario").val(idHorario);
            
        }
    });
}
```

E essa aqui pra salvar:

```js
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(Horarios h, string HoraInicio, string HoraFim, bool Seg, bool Ter, bool Qua, bool Qui, bool Sex, bool Sab, bool Dom, bool Fer, int Tipolimite, int Limiteacessos, int HorarioId)
        {
            h.Id = HorarioId;
            var item = new HorariosItens()
            {
                HoraFim = HoraFim,
                HoraInicio = HoraInicio,
                Seg = Seg,
                Ter = Ter,
                Qua = Qua,
                Qui = Qui,
                Sex = Sex,
                Sab = Sab,
                Dom = Dom,
                Fer = Fer,
                Tipolimite = Tipolimite,
                Limiteacessos = Limiteacessos,
                HorarioId = HorarioId,
               
            };
            //try
            //{
            ViewData["hor"] = HorarioId;
            _context.HorariosItens.Add(item);
                _context.SaveChanges();

            //HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
            //   .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == HorarioId).ToListAsync();

            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    throw ex;
            //}

            return new JsonResult(new { Resultado = item.Id });
        }
```

E depois nessa, onde deveria listar os horarios itens, porém não estou conseguindo trabalhar passando o id:

```js
 public IList<HorariosItens> HorariosItens { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
                  .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == int.Parse(ViewData["hor"].ToString())).ToListAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
                   .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == 0).ToListAsync();
            }
            //ViewData["HorarioId"] = new SelectList(_context.Horarios, "Id", "Nome");
            return Page();
        }
```

Coloquei até um try catch, porém ela smp cai no catch.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" id="idHorario"/>` deveria ser assim `<input type="hidden" id="idHorario" name="idHorario"/>` porque o que vale para a programação é o `name` do `input`!!!

Comment: Mesmo assim não consigo.

Comment: o que colocou no método ??? poruqe é mais ou menos assim: `GetAprovacaoEmendaById(int idHorario)` !!! pra resgatar!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta pra q vc possa entender. obrigado.

Comment: Aqui  `, data: { id: idHorario }` tenta `,data: { id: document.getElementById('idHorario').value }`

Comment: Mas ai passa o valor normal, eu preciso pegar pra trazer os itens, o idHorario ai, está preenchido.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve passar o valor do input hidden pro controller e depois passar para o método que faz a consulta:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAprovacaoEmendaById(tipododado valordoInput)
{
  HorariosItens horarios = SeuMetodoDeConsulta(valordoInput);  
}
```

E no seu método de consulta receber esse valor:

```
public HorariosItens(tipododado valordoInput)
{
  HorariosItens = await _context.HorariosItens
             .Include(a => a.Horarios).Where(a => a.HorarioId == valordoInput ).ToListAsync();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: o hidden já ta com o valor, eu preciso apenas utilizá-lo. na comparação, não to conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Comment: O valor do input hidden está no seu front ou no back-end?

Comment: Eu utilizo PageRazor, por javascript eu preenche o hidden que está no html create, e dentro do controle create eu preciso utilizar este hidden.

Comment: Você está conseguindo pegar esse valor no controller?

Comment: Consigo sim, editei a pergunta pra que você possa entender. Obrigado.